# Does WP fire delete_post when trashed posts are automatically deleted?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions, trash

I have a custom db table that stores additional post data and I need to delete posts from my custom table when the original post is deleted.

Will WP fire the `delete_post` action below and run `my_function` when WP *"automatically"* deletes posts that have been trashed?

```
add_action( 'delete_post', 'my_function');
```

I can set up an option to manually purge my custom table if needed but I would prefer it to happen automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

Yes, it does ;)

### Long answer

The function that is used to empty the trash/remove trashed posts is called [`wp_scheduled_delete`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_scheduled_delete/). When you'll take a look at [it's code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L4770), you'll see, that it uses `wp_delete_post` to delete the posts and inside `wp_delete_post` the action `delete_post` is run as you can see [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.6/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2605).